# An equality in $L^2(0,T;V')$!? Weak solution to PDE via Galerkin approximations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have the heat equation
$$u' - \Delta u = f$$
as equality in $L^2(0,T;V')$,i.e.,
$$(u',v) + (\nabla u, \nabla v) = (f,v)$$
for all $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$, where I used the same brackets for duality pairing and inner product for succinctness.

Let $w_j$ be the basis in $V$ and $H$. I read in a book that the finite dimensional (Galerkin) approximations to the PDE 
$$(u_n',w_j) + (\nabla u_n, \nabla w_j) = (f, w_j), \quad\text{for $j=1,...,n$}$$
can be written as
$$\frac{d}{dt}u_n - \Delta u_n = P_nf\tag{1}$$
where $P_n$ is a projection operator.

In what sense is this latter equation an equality? Presumable not an equality in $L^2(0,T;V')$ because the weak form I wrote above only holds for the basis functions. However, the author later takes an inner product of (1) with an element on $L^2(0,T;V)$, how can he do that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is indeed an abuse of notation though, by no means you could say (1) is an equality in $L^2(0,T;V')$, because (1) only holds in a finite dimensional subspace. Multiply (1) by the basis of the finite dimensional subspace
$$
(u_n',w_j) - (\Delta u_n,w_j) = (P_n f,w_j).
$$
Proper assumption about the boundary condition and continuity leads to:
$$
(u_n',w_j) - (\Delta u_n,w_j) = (u_n',w_j) + (\nabla u_n, \nabla w_j).
$$
Hence:
$$
(P_n f,w_j) = (f,w_j), \quad \text{for } j=1,\ldots,n,
$$
which is to say, $P_n f$ is the $L^2$-projection of $f$ onto this finite dimensional subspace.

I didn't see the paper, but I guess the reason to multiply a function in $L^2(0,T;V)$ is to get some a priori error estimate for this approximation by exploiting the fact that
$$
(u'-u_n',w_j) + \big(\nabla (u-u_n), \nabla w_j\big) = (f-P_n f,w_j).
$$

---

EDIT: question in the comment, instead of claiming (1) holds, rather what we can do is the following
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(u_n',\phi) + a(u_n,\phi)
\\
=& (u_n',P_n\phi) + a(u_n,P_n\phi) + (u_n',\phi - P_n\phi) + a(u_n,\phi-P_n\phi) 
\\
=& (P_n f,P_n \phi) + (u_n',\phi - P_n\phi) + a(u_n,\phi-P_n\phi) 
\\
=& (P_n f,\phi) + \color{blue}{(u_n',\phi - P_n\phi)} + \color{red}{a(u_n,\phi-P_n\phi) }.
\end{aligned}
$$
Blue term could vanish if we integrate w.r.t. time and integration by parts to move the derivative to $\phi-P_n \phi$. However for the red term to vanish, we must have something like $\Delta u_n = 0$...

---

EDIT2: If we say $f = g$ in $L^2(0,T;V')$, I don't know what the author did, but according to the Evans' book (see Section 7.1), it is 
$$\newcommand{\lsub}[2]{{\vphantom{#2}}_{#1}{#2}}
\lsub{V'}{\langle f(t,\cdot),v \rangle}_V = \lsub{V'}{\langle g(t,\cdot),v \rangle}_V,
$$
for any $v\in V$, at a.e. time $t\in [0,T]$. This is the same with what you wrote in the comment though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A thought occurred to me while reading it: since $(u_n', v) = (P_n u_n', v) = (P_n u_n', P_n v)$ by properties of the projection,and likewise with the other terms, maybe it does make sense as an equality in $L^2(0,T;V')$? Because we can take the pairing with any $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$ and use the calculation I just wrote. What do you think?

Comment: Once we do the projection, say $$(u_n',P_n v) + (\nabla u_n, \nabla (P_n v)) = (P_n f, P_n v).$$ Still $\{P_n v\}$ is finite dimensional even for all test function $v$, we still can't say this equation holds in $L^2(0,T;V')$.

Comment: I agree it's finite dimension but is that the definition of "equality?" As i understand, the equality holds in $L^2(0,T;V')$ if we can take the dual pairing with $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$ and that dual pairing makes sense.  Because eg. $(P_nf, v) = (P_nf, P_nv)$, the equation above (1) tells us that $(P_nf, v)$ makes sense, and similarly for the other terms.

Comment: So I guess it depends on defn. of equality??

Comment: @workl An equation $A u = f$ being valid in $L^2(0,T;V')$ is equivalent to say $\langle A u,v \rangle = \langle f,v \rangle$, for any $v\in V$. Notice $A u$ and $f$ are in $V'$. In the finite dimensional approximation, $(P_n f,v)$ certainly makes sense, and you can view $P_n f$ in $V'$ as well. But it is definitely not correct to state "(1) holds in $V'$": because $$(u_n',v) + (\nabla u_n,\nabla v) \neq (P_n f,v)$$ for all $v\in V$. Because $$(\nabla u_n,\nabla v)\neq (\nabla u_n,\nabla (P_n v))$$ in general. Did the author claim that?

Comment: Ah yes you're right. The author does the following: he chooses $\phi \in C^1(0,T;V)$ with $\phi(T) = 0$ in the weak form $(u',v) + a(u,v) = (f,v)$ (which is fine), and integrates this equation. Then he says: "if we do the same in the equation (1), we get $\int_0^T - (u_n, \phi') + a(u_n, \phi)ds = \int_0^T (P_nf, \phi)ds + (u_n(0), \phi(0))$ and then we take limits to conclude that the initial condition is satisfied."

Comment: So I am having trouble with "if we do the same in the equation (1)" -- he is taking inner product with $\phi \in C^1(0,T;V)$. It's not an element of the finite dimensional space so how does he do that!?

Comment: @workl $C^1(0,T;V)$ has only impacts on the time integration, rather than if (1) holds in $V'$ or not. $f(x,t) \in C^1(0,T;V)$ means the function $f(x,\cdot)\in V$ is smoothly evolving along with time. (Notice he did integration by parts in time variable)

Comment: Hmm. Let me make sure I am right: by equality of $f=g$ in $L^2(0,T;V')$, we mean $\int_0^T \langle f(t), v(t) \rangle_{V',V} = \int_0^T \langle g(t), v(t) \rangle_{V',V}$ for all $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$, right? This is not the same as what you write in your second last comment, where you chose $v \in V$ and the dual pairing is different. 

Also, I agree $C^1$ only refers to time. But with this definition of equality, I have no idea still how the equation I wrote in my second last comment can be true, given that the author states he uses (1) to obtain it.. maybe I misunderstand your point.

Comment: I will have a read of your edit carefully (thanks for your continued help btw).

Comment: Regarding your red term, I think it's fine if we integrate in time and use the bound in $V$ on the bilinear form $a$. It is given that $P_n\phi \to \phi$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$ by properties of the projection. So basically if we integrate and take the limit the term disappears. And the same for the blue term. It's getting late and I might have made a mistake but your way looks good!

Comment: @workl Hmm, if you are saying $P_n \phi \to \phi$, then you already have when $n\to \infty$, $\{w_j\}_{j=1}^n$ will span the whole $V$? By your question I thought we were only dealing with finite dimensional projection for fixed $n$.